# Problems with html tags putted out via php

Tags: php, html, quotes, double-quotes

my problem is basically this block of code:

```
  echo
  "<tr class='table_list_content' onclick = "window.location.href = 'zoom.projects.php&laquo'">".
    ...
  "</tr>";
```

Neither this way (above) nor that way (below) works:

```
  echo
  "<tr class='table_list_content' onclick = 'window.location.href = 'zoom.projects.php&laquo''>".
   ...
  "</tr>";
```

I guess due to the fact that I'm putting this HTML-Tag out with PHP I "ran out" of different types of quotes because when I put the same code out just without PHP I'm led to the page like I want and everything works perfectly fine. Is another kind of quotes or is there another solution. I'm sorry for any mistakes in this post aswell as I'm new to this I'm not a nativ speaker in English.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: use `\ ` to escape a char `"<tr class='table_list_content' onclick =\"window.location.href = 'zoom.projects.php&laquo'\">".`

Comment: Have a look at string blocks in PHP, this sort of systax: `<<<EOF ..... EOF;`.

Comment: One of the hazards with embedding some javascript inside a simple element while echoing the string with php. In addition to escaping quotes, you can move to a framework like jquery, and hook onto the class with click events, which open a whole new world of fun toys and abilities.

Comment: @IncredibleHat That sound nice but the problem is that im a bloody beginner in web-development and stuff. I heard about Frameworks but I have no idea where to start and how when I want to use one

Comment: Dont get too frustrated, all things have a beginning. Take a look into `jquery`, as its one of the most easy-to-pick-up javascript libraries (and widely supported). But as for your question here, all you need to do is escape quotes when you run out of different quotes to use. You can also end the php with `?>` and just put pure HTML, then begin the php again with `<?php` when you are done. Dont fret! Things will get easier :)